# How does a client connecting to a mobile device's acting as a hotspot send a message to a UDP server hosted by the mobile device?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, udp

I have an iPhone acting as a wifi hotspot.

I want other devices to be able to send UDP packets to a UDP server embedded within my app.

Since the other devices are connecting to the hotspot, do they really need to know the ip address ? How can they learn the ip address and port to send UDP packets to ?

Comment: I would suggest you look at mDNS (aka Bonjour). Then clients can find the service by name.

Comment: I am trying to use embedded devices, so I am looking for the simples possible solution.

Comment: You can try using broadcasting. Your only options are broadcasting, multi casting (which is what bonjour uses) or having a known/fixed is address. By default the iOS hotspot device is 172.10.10.1 but this probably isn't guaranteed forever